# scrape and clicking form with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I want to scrape the simulation "Richiedi il tuo prestito online" of a form of this website:

```html
https://www.findomestic.it/
```

I tried this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.findomestic.it/")
raison = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0);']")
montant = driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_importo')
submitButton = driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola')
actions = ActionChains(driver).click(raison).send_keys('AUTO NUOVA').click(montant).send_keys('2000').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
actions.perform()
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
print(driver)
driver.close()
```

My expected output is the result when you click on the form. I want to find the results of the web page with the interest rate and the amount.

[expected outpout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUSvZ.png)
But the print is not correct:

The result is just sends me back the session:

```
<selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.WebDriver(session="c4070330-18b2-11e9-81cf-2dbe9dae6b83")>
```

Comment: I already explained the problem and shared my code.

Comment: What is your *expected output*? Do you want to print simply all the text displayed on page?

Comment: My expected output is the result when you click on the form. I want to find the results of the web page with the interest rate and the amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print(driver)` returns the string representation of WebDriver instance (`driver.__str__()`) and it's normal behavior

`print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)` returns nothing as after you submit the form page `body` is *empty* - it contains only scripts that are not displayed on page and so `text` property returns empty string as expected

You need to wait for results to appear on page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.findomestic.it/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.select.bh-option"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AUTO NUOVA'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_id("findomestic_simulatore_javascript_importo").send_keys("2000")
driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola').click()

for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.fd-siff-element > li')))[1:]:
    print(item.text.split('\n')[:-1])
```

The output should be

```
['56,20 € PER', '42 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
['64,10 € PER', '36 MESI', '9,53 % TAN FISSO', '9,96 % TAEG FISSO']
['75,20 € PER', '30 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
['91,80 € PER', '24 MESI', '9,46 % TAN FISSO', '9,89 % TAEG FISSO']
['119,70 € PER', '18 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have an error when I add your code to mine

Comment: @Turing , which one? share exception

Comment: TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Turing , did you successfully pass the main page and navigate to result page?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. Can you pass me your entire code for me to test?

Comment: @Turing I didn't write the code for handling main page (I suppose that your code works correctly) and also I'm using Chrome instead of PhantomJS ([PhantomJS support is stopped](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/27/phantomjs-is-dead-use-chrome-headless-in-continuous-integration.html) and it's quite unreliable, so better not to use it)

Comment: I am on firefox, and I can not use the chrome driver. Do you have an idea to implement with PhantomJs?

Comment: @Turing , it might work with PhantomJS, but debugging of code in headless mode is quite problematic. Try to add `driver.save_screenshot('/path/to/sreenshot.png')` after line that submits the form and check whether you really navigates to next page

Comment: @Turing , I've updated answer with complete code. Try and let me know the result

Comment: There is always an error when you start the code. TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Here : for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.fd-siff-element > li')))[1:]:
    print(item.text.split('\n')[:-1])

Comment: @Turing , Are you sure that you using *updated code*? It works fine for me... Did you try it in headless mode only?

Comment: @Turing , what if to replace that line with `print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element('css', 'div.fd-siff-amounts').get_attribute('textContent')))`?

Comment: @Turing , and what about screenshot? Do you see the next page with results? Also did you try it with non-headless browser?

Comment: I looked at the screen, it still does not work. What do you mean by non-headless browser ?

Comment: @Turing I mean use something except PhantomJS. Normal browser :)

Comment: When I add time to sleep, I get that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvvzC.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186719/discussion-between-turing-and-andersson).

Answer (score 1):

To scrape the simulation "Richiedi il tuo prestito online" of a form of the [website](https://www.findomestic.it/) you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get("https://www.findomestic.it/ ")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.select.bh-option"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='select-list bh-options_list']//li/a[text()='Auto nuova']"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#findomestic_simulatore_javascript_importo").send_keys("2000")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola").submit()
```

Comment: It work, bu how can I print the result of price and other ? :)

Comment: As per your code trials you tried to `send_keys('AUTO NUOVA')` and `send_keys('2000')` and your expected output was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUSvZ.png). Hence was my answer. If your requirement have changed please raise a new question :)

Comment: But how could I print the result?

Comment: You have mentioned your expected output as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUSvZ.png) which you can easily get now through **driver.save_screenshot("filename")**. I am sure you tried that hence you commented **It work** :) Are you looking for something else?

Comment: The image is all gray, nothing is displayed! When I say when the code works, there is no error.

Comment: Not with my system right now. You can induce `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` once again for the _elements to be visible_. Incase you are in emergency induce `time.sleep(20)` and `driver.save_screenshot("filename")`