# Body print selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to display the result of my **scraping** from https://www.findomestic.it/, I'm getting an error

My code is here:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.findomestic.it/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.select.bh-option"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AUTO NUOVA'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_id("findomestic_simulatore_javascript_importo").send_keys("2000")
driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola').submit()
time.sleep(100)
driver.save_screenshot('sreenshot.png')
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.fd-siff-element > li')))[1:]:
    print(item.text.split('\n')[:-1])
```

My expected output

```
['56,20 € PER', '42 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
['64,10 € PER', '36 MESI', '9,53 % TAN FISSO', '9,96 % TAEG FISSO']
['75,20 € PER', '30 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
['91,80 € PER', '24 MESI', '9,46 % TAN FISSO', '9,89 % TAEG FISSO']
['119,70 € PER', '18 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
```

The following error occur:
[image: expected output]

Comment: It  appears that the element `ul.fd-siff-element > li` does not get visible within the waiting time of 10s.

Comment: What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have `set_window_size` to make it full screen.

And I have changed the locator to xPath:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedrive", chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.findomestic.it/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.select.bh-option"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AUTO NUOVA'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_id("findomestic_simulatore_javascript_importo").send_keys("2000")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn bh-btn"]').click()
# driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_form').submit()
time.sleep(100)
driver.save_screenshot('sreenshot.png')
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.fd-siff-element > li')))[1:]:
    print(item.text.split('\n')[:-1])
```

Hope this helps!

---

After the edit to maximize the window this is the output:

```
Le proposte selezionate per te
CONFRONTA OFFERTE
IL TUO PROGETTO
AUTO NUOVA
arrow_drop_down
IMPORTO
euro_symbol
ASSICURAZIONE
help_outline

50,20 € PER
48 MESI
9,45 %
TAN FISSO
9,87 %
TAEG FISSO
Importo richiesto 2.000,00 €
keyboard_arrow_up
check_circle
Selezionata per te
check_circle
Selezionata per te
save SALVA PREVENTIVO
compare_arrows CONFRONTA
RICHIEDI FINANZIAMENTO
56,20 € PER
42 MESI
9,54 % TAN FISSO
9,97 % TAEG FISSO
keyboard_arrow_down
64,10 € PER
36 MESI
9,53 % TAN FISSO
9,96 % TAEG FISSO
keyboard_arrow_down
75,20 € PER
30 MESI
9,54 % TAN FISSO
9,97 % TAEG FISSO
keyboard_arrow_down
91,80 € PER
24 MESI
9,46 % TAN FISSO
9,89 % TAEG FISSO
keyboard_arrow_down
119,70 € PER
18 MESI
9,54 % TAN FISSO
9,97 % TAEG FISSO
keyboard_arrow_down

picture_as_pdf PREVENTIVO/INFO EUROPEE DI BASE CREDITO CONSUMATORI
Messaggio pubblicitario con finalità promozionale. Offerta di prestito personale, valida per oggi,come da esempio rappresentativo: importo totale dovuto 2.409,60 €, spese di incasso rata 0,00 €, spese comunicazione periodica (almeno una all'anno) 0,00 €,imposta di bollo/sostitutiva addebitata sulla prima rata 0,00 €.
Al fine di gestire le tue spese in modo responsabile e di conoscere eventuali altre offerte disponibili, Findomestic ti ricorda, prima di sottoscrivere il contratto, di prendere visione di tutte le condizioni economiche e contrattuali, comprese eventuali condizioni relative alle opzioni di cambio rata e salto rata (attivabili dopo aver rimborsato le prime 6 rate), facendo riferimento alle Informazioni Europee di Base sul Credito ai Consumatori (IEBCC) disponibili nel processo online. Salvo approvazione di Findomestic Banca S.p.A.  
Findomestic Banca SpA . P.Iva 03562770481
Dati Societari | Trasparenza | Privacy | Sicurezza | Cookie | Codice di Condotta | Condizioni Assicurative
['56,20 € PER', '42 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
['64,10 € PER', '36 MESI', '9,53 % TAN FISSO', '9,96 % TAEG FISSO']
['75,20 € PER', '30 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
['91,80 € PER', '24 MESI', '9,46 % TAN FISSO', '9,89 % TAEG FISSO']
['119,70 € PER', '18 MESI', '9,54 % TAN FISSO', '9,97 % TAEG FISSO']
```

Comment: @Turing first this is a good question... what I have done in the edit is to make the window bigger and it worked for me let me know if this solves it!

Comment: The error is still there Is further enlarging the size of windows the problem will be solved?

Comment: @Turing I'll tell you the truth i=I am not using `set_window_size(1400,1000)` rather: `chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')` on `Chrome`... so it may be a good idea to think of doing it in Chrome... you have  `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` for runing headlees and `chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")`. **Buttom line:** Go ahead make the window biger!

Comment: @MosheSlavin Perhaps there is a lot of difference within the _Browsing Engines_ used by _Chrome_ and _PhantomJS_

Comment: @MosheSlavin Can you share your chrome code please? Because it still does not work

Comment: @Turing I have added the Chrome options... You will need to put the path to the chromedrive...

Comment: @DebanjanB you are correct... But the weird thing is that it doesn't work with chromedrive too... Unless you use the class and maximize the window...

Comment: @DebanjanB I'll have a look tomorrow too... ;) We need to convey that  PhantomJS in obsolete...

Answer (score 0):

It seem that `form` receives incorrect data when you triggers `submit` on Submit button instead of `click` (note that inserted `"2000"` value should be auto-converted to `2.000,00` which is not performed in case of `.submit()`)

Try to replace

```
driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola').submit()
```

with

```
driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola').click()
```

Comment: I have tried doing that too... but it did not work... only when I changed the locator to xPath: `//*[@class="btn bh-btn"]` it worked!

Comment: @MosheSlavin , hmm... But your solution is based on the same approach :) You've just used class names of Submit button instead of its `@id`

Comment: Yes! that's what's wired I did what you have answered myself but it did not work... therefore I use the className...

Comment: Do you have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: @MosheSlavin that's very weird as the button is found and the `@id` is unique, so even theoretically clicking the same button found by different locators cannot lead to different results. Are you sure that you really used `click()`? :) Can you double-check?

Comment: @MosheSlavin , no there is nothing that can change button behavior depends on selector. Also note that at least in Chrome `driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola').submit()` is not working while `driver.find_element_by_id('findomestic_simulatore_javascript_calcola').click()` work fine

Comment: @Turing , this is different error. It's web-app error that means that entered value is unacceptable. I advice you (again) not to use PhantomJS as it's deprecated, still has tons of bugs and thus might behave incorrectly

Comment: @Andersson As a _Selenium_ tag contributor it is plain _rude_ and _condescending_ to comment as _PhantomJS_ has tons of bugs. We as _PhantomJS_ team are trying to bridge the gap between current implementation and _W3C_ specifications in the best possible way. You are always welcome to contribute for the same.

Comment: @Andersson Could you share your code with Chrome driver please?

Comment: @Turing , I used exactly the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199256/scrape-and-clicking-form-with-selenium/54199602#54199602) , but instead of `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()` I used `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: @DebanjanB It's not rude or condescending to say that PhantomJS has tons of bugs... it's currently got [1,823](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues)... you can dispute the definition of "tons" but that's a LOT of bugs and development has been stopped on it. Generally it's not advisable to use a tool that is no longer in development, especially when there is a good alternative like chrome headless. Who is this "we as PhantomJS team" that you speak of when development has stopped and the project was [archived](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344) almost a year ago?